# Input:checked update material of mesh

Tags: javascript, jquery, three.js

I would like to change the material of my mesh if I check a radio button.
Basicially I want to catch the data-color attribute of the checked radio button and put it inside the material of my mesh.

How could this be done?

**Materials**

```
 var material = {
      "black":  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0x111111,  shininess: 35, combine: THREE.MixOperation, shading: THREE.FlatShading } ),
      "white":  new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xffffff,  shininess: 65}),
      "grey":   new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( {color: 0xcccccc,  specular: 0x111111})
      }
```

**Mesh**

```
var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry( 1, 1, 1 );
var mesh= new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material[ "black" ]);
mesh.name = "changematerial";
scene.add( mesh );
```

**Radio button**

```
<input id="black" type="radio" data-color="black" name="material" checked>
<input id="white" type="radio" data-color="white" name="material">
<input id="grey" type="radio" data-color="grey" name="material">
```